# Free Code Camp Challenge - Seek and Destroy

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop, variadic-functions

I am working on the challenge Seek and Destroy (intro to JavaScript) and even after reading through multiple answers I'm not understanding.  I'd like to know if my thought process is valid more than what is wrong with my syntax, though both would be appreciated.

**Problem**

"*You will be provided with an initial array as the first argument to the destroyer function, followed by one or more arguments. Remove all elements from the initial array that are of the same value as these arguments.*

*The function must accept an indeterminate number of arguments, also known as a **variadic function**. You can access the additional arguments by adding a rest parameter to the function definition or using the arguments object.*"

This is the initial code below:

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  return arr;
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Here is how far I've gotten with my thought process in comments.

```
//unsure how to deal with variable amounts of arugments I tried to copy "variadic function" examples but really don't understand the syntax of them.  

function destroyer(arr,...remove) {

    //create empty array to hold where we push elements to
    const ourArray = [];

   //iterate through each element
    for (let i = 0; i< arr.length, i++;)


    //check that each element does not = arguments
      while (i != ...remove) {
    // keep push unique elements to the new array
        ourArray.push(i);
          i++;
}
      
  return ourArray;
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

This is my first time posting so I hope I made the question clear. Please use beginner friendly vocab, Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out a few things I wasn't understanding.  Posting here for future learners who also wanted to use the spread operator (...).
[This Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u87hVjC8FFI&t=2s) was SUPER helpful.

Solution from Video

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  const argsArr = [...arguments].slice(1);

  const filteredArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){
    if(!argsArr.includes(arr[i])){
      filteredArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return filteredArr;
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

**Problems/misunderstanding I had.**

1. I didn't realize that the function would only have one input (arr) and I didn't need to include "...remove" to represent an unknow amount of arguments.
2. Didn't know I needed to use the keyword "arguments"
3. I still don't understand how "filter" works well enough to implement it.

I'm a beginner but I'm trying, I hope this helps someone.